# Non-debug qlmanage

Tags: terminal, bash, quicklook

I've got a `bash` alias set up in my terminal, `alias quicklook='qlmanage -p '`, in order to easily quicklook files from the terminal, but the output bugs me.

`Testing Quick Look preview with files:
    /Users/Amory/Desktop/todo.txt
2015-09-01 14:36:40.257 qlmanage[36196:507] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x3e2f, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
2015-09-01 14:36:40.258 qlmanage[36196:507] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x9137, name = 'com.apple.CFPasteboardClient'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
2015-09-01 14:36:40.269 qlmanage[36196:507] Failed to allocate communication port for com.apple.CFPasteboardClient; this is likely due to sandbox restrictions`

Moreover, compared to invocation via the spacebar, the preview has a big "DEBUG" in the title bar and is just generally not the same.  Why is this?  Is there a way around the debug mode from the terminal?  The `-d` options only make it worse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Send the debug output to /dev/null

```
alias quicklook='qlmanage -p "$@" >& /dev/null'
```

No clue on how to remove the [DEBUG] from the window title

Comment: Fair enough!  I went with `2> /dev/null` to keep the moderately helpful first line.